# The type or namespace name 'ClaimsIdentity' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've added these usings and I have the nuget packages installed. Why can I not use Claim? Visual Studio says ClaimsIDentity, Claim and ClaimTypes could not be found.

~/Controllers/AccController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class AccController : Controller
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }

            // Don't do this in production!
            if (model.Email == "admin@admin.com" && model.Password == "password")
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Ben"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "a@b.com"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Country, "England")
            },
                    "ApplicationCookie");

                var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
                var authManager = ctx.Authentication;

                authManager.SignIn(identity);

                return Redirect(GetRedirectUrl(model.ReturnUrl));
            }

            // user authN failed
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid email or password");
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to add this in your code:

```
using System.Security.Claims;
```